# EF 3.1: Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure `GetVideo` in a SQL Server 2019 database that does this:

```
select 
    [video.id] = vid,
    [video.title] = title
from 
    videos
for json path, root('x');
```

Which returns this JSON:

```
{
    "x": 
    [
    {
        "video": 
        {
            "id": 11,
            "title": "Forest Gump"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "video": 
        {
            "id": 22,
            "title": "Merry Christmas"
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

However using C# and EF Core 3.1 generates an error:

> Sequence has no elements

```
public class Sp
{
    public List<video> XV {get; set;}

    public class video
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public string title {get; set;}
    }
}

public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Sp>>> X()  // Task<IActionResult> same error
{
    // this line throws "Sequence has no elements", same for .ToArrayAsync()
    var v = await _context.Sp.FromSqlRaw("dbo.GetVideo").ToListAsync(); 
    return Ok(a);
}
```

**Update**

1. My `DbContext` class does have this line omitted in original question: `public virtual DbSet<Sp> Sp { get; set; }.`
2. `.FromSqlRaw()` always works for calling a stored procedure. That is, it works without `for json path, root('x')` in stored procedure along with `builder.Entity<SP>().HasNoKey()`.

Unfortunately I'm locked in with JSON being returned from SQL Server and EF Core version 3.1. At the moment I'm wondering if `DbSet<Sp>` is right because it may expects table-like returns therefore *Sequence contains no elements?*

I need to find a way to call a stored procedure which returns JSON instead of table-like data.

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: @DaleK Question is updated. method X() received "Sequence has no elements"

Comment: Are you sure that `FromSqlRaw` accepts just a table name? I don't know either way but my first guess would be that you 'd have to provide an actual query.

Comment: @jmcilhinney `FromSqlRaw` is calling the stored proc named `GetVideo`. I've been using it successfully for table-like returns, but not sure if stored proc is returning JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to break your `_context.FromSqlRaw()` and `ToListAsync()` into two separate lines and make sure that the first one is not returning an empty list. I'm not familiar with the `FromSqlRaw`, but "sequence contains no elements" is probably the result of trying to do something to an IEnumerable when the referenced collection is empty.

```
var v = await _context.Sp.FromSqlRaw("dbo.GetVideo");
if (v.Any()) return Ok(await v.ToListAsync());
return NotFound();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, from what you shared it looks like `class Video` should be your entity class (note I'm calling it `Video` with a capital `V` because that is recommended in all coding guidelines).

You did not share it with us, but please make sure you have this in your DB Context class:

```
public DbSet<Video> Videos { get; set; }
```

To make this easier, place `class Video` outside of the wrapper class `SP`, then maybe even *remove* class `SP`.

After that I see 2 options:

**Option 1**: change the stored procedure

... to contain just `SELECT vid AS id, title FROM videos`.

That should return exactly the data that `_context.Videos.FromSqlRaw()` expects. Note: it definitely does not expect JSON. For more info, see [Microsoft Learn: Using SQL queries with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries).

The code to run the SP would become something like this:

```
var list = await _context.Videos.FromSqlRaw("dbo.videos").ToListAsync();
```

**Option 2**: drop the stored procedure, forget about writing SQL (my favourite option)

... and do just this:

```
var list = await _context.Videos.ToListAsync();
```

This is what normal EF Core code would and should do. No stored procedures are needed. Writing your own SQL is almost never needed, because EF Core will generate proper SQL for you on the fly.

One more thing: you will now run into the problem that the database table uses `vid` while class Video uses `id`. The solution would be to change either `vid` to `id` (in the DB Table), or change `id` to `vid` (in the Video class).

It is a ground rule of EF Core that *property names of Entity classes* match with *column names in the database tables*. Maybe there are ways to make it work if they don't match, but I wouldn't know if there are, and it's just easiest and clearest if they are the same.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the details. 1) DbContext class does have a line omitted in original question: `public virtual DbSet<Sp> Sp { get; set; }`. 2) it works without `FOR json path, root('x')` in stored proc along with `builder.Entity<SP>().HasNoKey()`. Unfortunately I'm locked in with JSON being returned from SQL and EF version is 3.1